# How to convert datatable into Entity Framework classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

I'd like to run a stored procedure (for performance issues I preferred stored procedures) and at the end I'd like to have module like the one below.

Do you also think in order to achieve this stored procedure is a better solution?

[image]

And, if I use a stored procedure, I'd like to preserve my EF structure. So, I probably need to convert the `DataTable` from the stored procedure into the EF class structure.

Does .NET have some sort of method that handles this conversion or do I have to build up something myself?

And once again, do you really think to do this with a **stored procedure** is **better** approach than **getting the data over EF**, and **develop some algorithm on ASP.NET C# to make it look like** the one on the picture I uploaded? And if you could also provide ***WHY***, that would be really awesome.

Thank you very much

Comment: The last part of your post is a request for opinion, and in my opinion, the primary advantage to sticking to sprocs is the separation of your data and application tiers. I would assume that if performance is /that/ big of an issue, your DBA probably isn't going to give you the option of using EF.

Comment: If you're using EF - I don't see any big benefit in using stored procedures - most definitely not a performance benefit. A well crafted and properly parametrized "inline" SQL query is just as performant as a stored procedure, stays in cache just as long as a stored procedure - there's really not much to gain from stored procedures in terms of performance...

Comment: Hi marc, but SPs are precompiled queries which, in theory , run faster. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to convert a DataTable to an EF entity? You don't have to use a DataTable to get the results from a stored procedure, you can retrieve EF objects directly from stored procedures

Have a look at this article

[Stored Procedures in the Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx)